# What is an effective way to farm stinkbugs?

Tags: grounded

What is an effective way to farm stinkbugs? What armor and weapons do you use and what methods work best (i.e. stand on a rock)?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you add what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the Ladybug armor.  It seems to be super effective at protecting against attacks.  Before I had the ladybug armor, I was using acorn armor, which was good, but still made it pretty difficult to take down anything larger than an ant.

I also have the Ant Club, which is good at stunning an enemy, before wailing on it.

Load up on smoothies ahead of time, those are also essential at taking down higher level bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Stinkbugs are weak to stabbing damage; try fighting them with arrows, spears, or needle weapons.

If you equip a gas mask, you'll be immune to their gas attacks. They don't do anything else while releasing gas, so you'll have a large window of opportunity to get some hits in with no risk of taking damage.

I find that they go down more easily with melee than with ranged weapons.